# ASP.NET MVC 3 display decimal value(18,1) in model from SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, decimal

I have a question for decimal value for set on model.
In my SQL server, displaySize field type is decimal(18,1)
How can I set the decimal type in model?

When I set like

```
 public decimal displaySize { get; set; }
```

It display like 21.00 not 21.
If I put 3.7, then it come out 3.70.

How do I set decimal format?
It sounds simple question, but I am beginner MVC 3 currently. 
Could you give some answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [DisplayFormatAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) on your model property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.###}")]
public decimal displaySize { get; set; }
```

The above will output a number with up to 3 decimal places.

Other [custom numeric formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) and [standard numeric formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) can also be used.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution solves my headache.

Answer (score 5):

You could define a display format:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal displaySize { get; set; }
```

and then in your strongly typed view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.displaySize)
```

or:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.displaySize)
```